# The general solution of a first order, linear PDE

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Having seen some linear PDEs, I'm pretty sure that the following holds

> The general solution of the PDE
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^na_i(x)u_{x_i}(x)=b(x) $$
>   where $u:D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function of $n$ real variables, is given by
>   $$ u(x)=F(\phi_1(x),\phi_2(x),\dots,\phi_{n-1}(x)) $$
>   where $\{\phi_i \}$ are some particular functions (independent in some sense), while $F$ is arbitrary.

I'd like to know if the above is indeed true, preferably with a reference.

Thanks.

Comment: This is too general, so of course it is true. If you take $\phi_i(x)=x_i$, then with $F$ arbitrary, any function can be expressed this way! (so the solution can as well, trivially)

Comment: @Jeff sorry, there should be only $n-1$ functions $\phi_i$. EDIT: I also meant that ANY function $F$ should give a solution.

Comment: I see, well if it is true, the proof would probably follow the method characteristics. Try chapter 3 in Evans PDE book.